# Why is dynamic power in this simulation with rectangular input voltage wrong?

Tags: power, basic

The following circuit models the output of an inverter (voltage magnitude is 1V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fil2ZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The dynamic power should be independent of R1 and given as \$P=CV^2f=400n\cdot50k=20mW\$.
In the simulation, I measure the current flowing through V1 and calculate the rms value (standard deviation). This current should match 20mA (such that power is 20mW). However, this is not the case. More so, the rms current strongly depends on the value of R1.

Where is the issue?

Comment: Your equation describes average power. RMS current is meaningless here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think this is the key to the answer. If I use `Pavg=0.5*mean(abs(current))` the result matches 20mW (for small enough R) but this doesn't make sense to me. In terms of (average) power, we're always using rms values. Also Wikipedia writes Pavg=Vrms*Irms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#Average_electrical_power). Can you elaborate?

Comment: The equation \$P_{AVG} = V_{RMS} \times I_{RMS}\$ is only valid for purely resistive loads. The Wikipedia article begins by assuming a resistive load, but that kind of slips through the cracks later. In this case, your load is resistance and capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

The expression o power given by you is valid when capacitor charges/discharges completely from 0 to VDD. Resistance will givern your time constant of circuit so more the resistance, more is charging time, and will therefore, will decrease the dynamic power of circuit.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and is part of the answer. My other confusion is what formula exactly to use if I have the time domain current waveform \$i(t)\$ (see comments of original post). Could you add how to express \$P_{avg}\$ as a function of \$i(t)\$ and what assumptions I need to make?

Comment: The generalized formula for average power is given by integral of product of V(t) and i(t) over a time period, giving total energy, and dividing this by time period of intrest

Answer (score 0):

> *In the simulation, I measure the current flowing through V1 and
> calculate the rms value (standard deviation).*

OK

> *This current should match 20mA (such that power is 20mW). However,
> this is not the case. More so, the rms current strongly depends on the
> value of R1.*

Consider when R1 is infinite in value; the current has to be zero coming from the voltage source. In other words current is highly dependent on the value of R1.

> *Where is the issue?*

Well, if the current changes with R1, that's pretty much what you should expect from your circuit.

> *The dynamic power should be independent of R1*

It can't be.